# how to loop through a list of checkboxs using jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to loop through a list of checkboxs using jquery?

Here's the code...

```
         $("input:checked").parent().find("strong").text();
```

Tried this but not working...

```
         $("input:checked").parent().find("strong").text().each(function()
         {
             alert(this);
         });
```

Comment: `.text` is a function which returns a **string** not a jQuery object.

Comment: typo on the text method and corrected but still not working

Comment: As I said, `.text()` returns a string and strings don't have an `.each` method. If you want to iterate over all `strong` elements, then omit `.text()`. You should read the jQuery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/) it explains how the methods work.

Comment: What do you want to *do* with the checkboxes? And what's the relevant HTML?

Comment: I want to take the text of selected checkboxs and add them to a textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.each($('input[type=checkbox]'), function(){
   doSomething();
});
```

Comment: That looks very wrong... did you mean `$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){...`?

Comment: I don't think you can pass a string to `$.each` and let it interpret as selector... at least the docs don't mention it. And my test shows otherwise: http://jsfiddle.net/48cwc/.

Comment: Then please quote that part. I'm not able to find it.

Comment: Oh, I'm dumb. Haha. You're 100% right. Fixed answer. Wasn't thinking.

Comment: "how to loop through a list of checkboxs using jquery?" Was your question. find("strong") will return all of the strong tags in the parent. I just copied what you had as the DoSomething() in the loop.

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene I removed it. What are you trying to accomplish by looping the inputs?

Comment: Still, `$.each` is generic method, if you are dealing with a jQuery object, `$(...).each(...)` is more appropriate.

Comment: @FelixKling is that faster than my version? I'm new to jQuery, so many of the nuances are unknown to me.

Comment: I honestly don't know (it's unlikely to make a difference) but it's more in line with how to write jQuery.